# TypeErr0r: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Tags: python-3.x

```
import math
r = input("Enter length from center : ")

s = 2*r*math.sin(math.radians(36))

area = 3*math.sqrt(3)*s*s/2.0

print ("Pentagon area :"+ str(area))



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 4, in <module>
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'
```

Answer (score 1):

By default values given by a `input()` are strings.

> The function then reads a line from input, converts it to a string (stripping a trailing newline), and returns that.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input

To perform arithmetic they must be of type `float()` or `int()`.

`int()` converts integers only so this will lose any decimal values.

To handle decimal points `float()` is needed:

> Return a floating point number constructed from a number or string.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float

You can convert your input to type float like this:

```
r = float(input("Enter length from center : "))
```

Comment: [input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a `string`. If you convert to int you'll lose precision.

Comment: @MFisherKDX. Thank you very much for correcting me.  I have edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

[input](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string. `math.sin` returns a float. You can't multiply a `string` by a `float` hence the error.

You want to multiply two numbers. Convert your string to a floating point number by calling `float()`.

```
s = 2*float(r)*math.sin(math.radians(36))
```

You actually *can* multiply a string by an int. `'a'*5` evaluates to `'aaaaa'`